# Sum of courses booked, SQL

Tags: sql, sum

Working on a query to calculate the total sum of the current courses booked, the cost of a course is shown in the course table, the current courses booked are shown in the booking table how would i get the sum of the total price for the current courses booked?

Course Table:

``````````````````````````````
   CourseId             cost
     `````````````````````````````
     96                 300
     32                 400
     25                 500
     62                 600
``````````````````````````````

Booking table:

``````````````````````````````
BookidId          CourseId
 `````````````````````````````
 1                 96
 2                 96
 3                 96
 4                 62
``````````````````````````````

The end result should be

```
CourseIdTot        Total
---------------------
96               900
62               600
```

Will need a join but not sure how to * the total of the courses booked with the cost over different course Ids. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with a join and `SUM`

```
SELECT c.courseId AS courseIdTot, SUM(cost) AS Total
FROM course AS c
INNER JOIN booking AS b
ON c.courseId = b.courseId
GROUP BY c.courseId
```

Answer (score 2):

Try joining two tables like:

```
SELECT c.courseId AS courseIdTot, SUM(cost) AS Total
FROM Course c INNER JOIN Booking b
ON   c.CourseId = b.CourseId
GROUP BY c.courseId
```